# How to make sure all the images are the same orientation?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, opencv, python

I am trying to do an shoes image classification task and want to make sure my input data all have the same orientation.

The majority of the images have the shoes pointing to the right:
[Right pointing shoe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hy7L.png)

But some of the shoes are pointing to the left:
[Left pointing shoe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuV1E.jpg)

I would like to make sure that all images point to the right and if they are pointed to the left, I would like to mirror that image. Is there a way in Python to automatically detect the correct orientation of an image?

Comment: Have you tried something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58635486/11365539. Although you might have trouble identifying the white area of that left pointing shoe since it's close in color to the background.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to have all the shoes facing the same direction. Won't the model be more generalised if the shoe can be facing any direction?

Comment: @Warpstar22 Thanks! this seem like a good lead.

Comment: @soumith Because one class had every shoe pointed to the right, and the other class has mixed orientations. I dont want the model to learn the orientation but the design patterns instead. Not sure if that's a good idea

Comment: @AndrewZhao For the class which has all shoes pointed to the right, you can use image augmentation so that the model learns different orientations of this particular shoe. More info here - https://markku.ai/post/data-augmentation/

Comment: @AndrewZhao Please check my answer and let me know if you need more clarity in solving your problem.

Comment: @GaneshTata Got it thanks!

Comment: @AndrewZhao If the answer helped you to solve your problem, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In image classification tasks, it is important to curate your dataset such that it encapsulates the different variations present in the data. This is to ensure that your model generalizes well, and it can predict accurately on unseen data. This is where image augmentation is helpful, since it enables you to augment the dataset to account for variations in data that were initially not present.

For instance, as you mentioned in one of your comments, one of the classes consists of all shoes pointed to the right. So, are all shoes in the test data / real-word data of this class also oriented to the right? Since this is highly unlikely, it is important to account for different orientations of the shoe for each class.

If this is one of the images in your training data -
        [image: wide demo pic]

Then through augmentation you can include the left oriented image(s) in the training data - 
[image: wide demo pic]

For more information, please refer to [data augmentation](https://markku.ai/post/data-augmentation).