# How to get the rotation of and object given its Axis-aligned bounding box coordinates Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, contour

Below is a function that return a bbox_coordinates and a binary image.

```
def back_projectcam1(histm,hsv_histt,hsvt): #hist: model histogram, hsv_histt: target image histogram, hsvt: hsv image of the target image
 track_window=None
 Mask = cv2.calcBackProject([hsvt],[0,1],histm,[0,180,0,256],1)
 Open=cv2.morphologyEx(Mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel1)
 #Filter=cv2.filter2D(Open,-1,kernel3,Open)
 erosion = cv2.erode(Open,kernel1,iterations = 1)
 dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel1,iterations = 2)
 Close=cv2.morphologyEx(dilation,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel1)
 _,thresh = cv2.threshold(Close,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
 #dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel1,iterations = 1)

 contours =cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 if contours[2] is not None:
  cntss = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
  cnt=max(cntss, key=cv2.contourArea) 
  x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
 
  
  track_window=x,y,w,h

 return track_window,thresh
```

How can i calculate the rotation form the returned coordinates (track_window). I know that i can get the rotation using `cv2-minAreaRect()` by passing the founded contours. However, i want to find the rotation using the returned bbox_coordinates and without having to find the contours

Comment: That is just not possible. The bounding rectangle doesn’t contain enough information to tell you something about the orientation of the object. You need to process the pixels inside it.

Comment: You need to get the rotated bounding box using cv2.minAreaRect. It outputs the orientation. An axis aligned bounding box will always have zero rotation. You can also approach it by using image moments or possibly connected components with stats

Comment: @fmw42. I've applied cv2.minAreaRect(). Do you know why it returns -0 and -90 degree when the train drives horizontally ?

Comment: See the angle correction comments at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/ or example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58632469/how-to-find-the-orientation-of-an-object-shape-python-opencv